# Handling a coordinate generated outside coverage

Tags: java, gis, repast-simphony

Is there any way to check if the point/coordinate to handle the exception and the problem described below.

I have tried creating an envelope from the grid coverage (from the raster file), but that doesnt seem to work.

```java
    GridCoverage2D c1 = geography.getCoverage("layer1"); // this is a raster layer
    Envelope2D e1 = c1.getEnvelope2D();
    DirectPosition pos = new DirectPosition2D(lat, lon);
    if(e1.contains(pos))
    //point is valid
```

I get the following exception in spite of checking the point location as shown in the code:

```
org.opengis.coverage.PointOutsideCoverageException: Coordinate (42.82, 10.608) is outside coverage.
at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D.evaluate(GridCoverage2D.java:479)
at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D.evaluate(GridCoverage2D.java:414)
at org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D.evaluate(GridCoverage2D.java:355)
```

Comment: Could you include your code following `if(e1.contains(pos))`? It would also be helpful if you could include and point out the line that throws the top-level `PointOutsideCoverageException`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to switch the order of lat,lon in the DirectPosition2d constructor so that it reads:

```
DirectPosition pos = new DirectPosition2D(lon, lat);
```

The exception is not being thrown from the code sample you posted, rather it occurs later when you call coverage.evaluate(pos) because the position is actually not valid. Geotools expects a (lon,lat) axis order by default - see https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/order.html